# How to convert Atari (65XE) tapes to ATR?

Tags: atari, emulation, data-transfer

I still have some tapes for my Atari 65XE and I'd like to play some of the old games I got.  But I don't have the Atari anymore.

I have a tape recorder of quality surpassing the Atari one by quite a bit though, and a PC with a good audio input capable of sampling the signal at well above the standard 600 baud of Atari tape storage.

Is there some way to dump these games to PC and convert them to ATR files - the emulator images?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, you're asking about two separate things here. The first is "how to get my tapes to a PC" and second is "how to convert tape records into a disk file/image".

The former can be solved with http://turgen.sourceforge.net, the latter is a bit more complicated. There had been many native tools for this task but the conversion is not always possible -- for instance many tape games load to awfully low addresses in RAM (overwriting the DOS) or use a copy protection or load parts into RAM after some point in game etc.

However, if you don't have anything special on those tapes (i.e. just classic games/programs), I'd suggest to google for them first, they might be available in ATR/XEX format already (http://a8.fandal.cz is a good start).

Comment: Thanks for the half of the answer. I'm asking them together because one is pretty much useless without the other -  performing the dumps from tape is quite pointless if you can't run what you dumped; and if you can run such a dump, you must obtain it somehow first, and it's not a common distribution format, so performing the dump is necessary as well. (kinda like "load, run" sequence, one is useless without the other.)

Comment: That's not entirely correct -- you can run tape dumps in an emulator without any problem, no need to convert it into ATR/XEX.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this page, especially the wav2cas en cas2wav programs.
I think this is what you need.
http://home.planet.nl/~ernest/atarixle.html

Comment: Bo, thank you for the link. It would be great if you could point out the information to look for or even include some. Otherwise this may seam like a less than desirable 'link only' answer.

Comment: [answer] might help you with this.